# Passing a variable as the arguments for Date.UTC()

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, utc

I want to pass the arguments for Date.UTC() as an array stored in a variable instead of a series of arguments.

```
let dateArray = [2019, 0, 1, 0]; 
let utcTime = new Date(Date.UTC(dateArray));
```

returns NaN

Of course this doesn't work because the object only accepts its arguments one after the other.  Like so;

```
let utcTime = new Date(Date.UTC(dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2], dateArray[3]);
```

returns 1546300800000

The problem is that I want it to work regardless of the length of the array in the variable.

```
let newYear = [2020];
let christmasDay = [2019,11,25];
let lunchTime = [2019,11,25,12,30];
```

Is there a way of passing these different variables as the arguments for the Date object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator:

```js
[
  [2020],
  [2019, 11, 25],
  [2019, 11, 25, 12, 30]
].forEach(function(dateArray) {
  let utcTime = new Date(Date.UTC(...dateArray));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(dateArray) + " becomes " + utcTime.toISOString());
});
```

Comment: There is no [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). ;-)